# Accessing Multiple Application in Multi-App CodeIgniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

Initially I had an single application CodeIgniter project but now I need to build an multi-application CodeIgniter project by replicating the existing.

So now my structure is as follows :

```
cms(main_folder)
-assets
-includes
-system
-index.php
-cms_test.php
-.htaccess
-application
--cms
---config
---controllers
---models
---views
--cms_test
---config
---controllers
---models
---views
```

In index.php I have made changes as follows :

```
$application_folder = 'application/cqms';

$system_path = 'system';
```

In cms_test.php I have made changes as follows :

```
$application_folder = 'application/cms_test';

$system_path = 'system';
```

For .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|cms_test\.php|images|robots\.txt)

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^cms_test$ cms_test\.php [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^cms_test\/(.*)$ cms_test\.php/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index\.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

The existing cms modules is working but I have problem in access new  application(i.e. cms_test).

Below is config detail of cms_test/config/config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/cms/cms_test.php';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

I able to access modules by using the following link :

> http://localhost/cms/cms_test.php/home

But in this case I'm not able to load assets files (i.e. css, js, other files)

> "NetworkError: 404 Not Found -
>   http://localhost/cms/cms_test.php/assets/

I tried to set the $config['base_url'] as empty due which I was able to fetch files from assets but it also redirect all the links to **http://localhost/cms/** instead of **http://localhost/cms/cms_test.php**

I have tried changing the base_url as follows

> $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/cms/cms_test/';

Then if get an 404 Page Not Found Error.

For temporary solution I'm trying to load all the assets files using proper path. i.e. in cms_test/config/constant.php below is constant define

```
define('ABSOLUTE_PATH', 'http://localhost/cqms/');
```

In kernal using ABSOLUTE_PATH for fetching all assets files

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo ABSOLUTE_PATH ."assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"; ?>">
```

I want know if there is a way to access the assets using below base_url as defined in the config.

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/cms/cms_test.php';
```

Below are the links which I have referred

> https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/managing_apps.html
>
> https://philsturgeon.uk/codeigniter/2009/07/08/Create-an-Admin-panel-with-CodeIgniter/

Comment: Why don't you use HMVC https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc

Comment: Also with base url dont have .php

Comment: Instead of doing this messy code you can use HMVC in codeigniter like @wolfgang1983 said. It will be more easy and manageable.

Comment: Thanks  wolfgang1983. But I don't want to make any changes in the existing application. As per your suggestion for using HMVC, I have rebuilt by entire project around it. This would be helpful in case of entire new project.